# Why must $A\subset B$ and $A \cap C = \varnothing$ for $A \cap (B-C) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I really don't understand how I'm supposed to prove that $A \cap C = \varnothing$ . And why can't, for instance, B be a subset of A?

Comment: It is confusing: What are you given and what do you want to prove?

Comment: @JimmyR. It seems to be $A \cap (B-C) = A\implies (A\subseteq B\land A\cap C=\varnothing)$, for all sets $A, B$ and $C$.

Comment: @Geir Do you know the definition of $X\subseteq Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to show if $A \cap (B - C) = A$ then both $A \subseteq B$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

Well, the first thing you have to realize is that $B - C = B \cap C^{c}$, where $C^{c}$ is the complement of $C$.  To convince yourself of this, draw two circles which overlap a little.  Call one of them $B$ and the other $C$.  $B - C$ is the part of $B$ that doesn't overlap with $C$.  Hopefully you'll see that this is the part of $B$ outside of $C$, i.e, in $C^{c}$, i.e., $B- C = B \cap C^{c}$.

Now, $A \cap (B - C) = A \cap (B \cap C^{c})$.

So we have $A \cap B \cap C^{c} = A$.  Notice that the left hand side of this equality is a subset of $C^{c}$.  Since this subset of $C^{c}$ equals $A$, that means $A \cap C = \emptyset$ (do you see why?).

Also, $A \cap B \cap C^{c}$ is a subset of $B$.  So we have that this subset of $B$ equals $A$.  Of course that implies $A \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 3):

**Draw a diagram.**

Here's a Venn diagram with $B\setminus C$ marked in green:

[image: B minus C]

And then here's one with $A\cap(B\setminus C)$ marked in red:

[image: A cap (B minus C)]

If we're given that $A\cap(B\setminus C)$ equals $A$, then every element in $A$ must be in the red area. This area is completely *outside* $C$, so $A$ and $C$ must be disjoint, but it is completely *inside* $B$, so $A$ must be a subset of $B$.

$A$ doesn't have to be a **strict** subset of $B$, though -- it is possible under your assumptions that $A$ and $B$ are the same set.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For any two sets $\;X,Y\;$ , we have that $\;X\cap Y=X\iff X\subset Y\;$ , so in your case you have that $\;A\subset B\setminus C\;$ ...